# "npm install" does not install @angular/cli, @angular/compiler-cli and @angular-devkit/build-angular properly

Tags: angular-cli, npm-install, ng-build

I am trying to install npm using the `npm install` command, and all the packages are installed except @angular/cli, @angular/compiler-cli and @angular-devkit/build-angular.

I tried installing them individually, but it is not working. Please tell me how to fix this problem.

Illustration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have `production` set to true in your environment, which will prevent the members of devDependencies from being installed. You can install them anyway under that circumstance passing the `--production` option with the install command, like:

```
npm install --production=false
```

You can read more about how dependencies are installed and handled by NPM in the [NPM documentation for the install command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install). The future should note that this link is to the v7 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
npm link @angular/cli
```

In my case, I looked in the `node_modules` folder, and angular seemeded to be there, but the `ng` command was still not available. the command above fixed that for me.  I also tried to delete the entire `node_modules` folder and redo the `npm install` but this did not solve it.